# Mount and Pycharm

Tags: mount, pycharm

Initially, I had to manually mount the secondary drive each time, but I decided to set up auto-mounting. However, after configuring auto-mounting, my PyCharm IDE was unable to find the mounted drive.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear. Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Also, provide some additional context around the issue that you've encountered: what version of PyCharm IDE are you using? Do other applications have issues with the auto-mounted drive? How, specifically, did you set up auto-mounting? Thanks